# How do I setup a Rails 3 jQuery view to show a list of states, then list cities belonging to that state?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `State` model which `has_many :cities` and a `city` model which `belongs_to :state`.
I want to show a list of States, then when a user clicks on a State make an ajax call to show the cities belonging to that state below.

I'm sure this can be done using jQuery and without partials, I'm just having trouble coming up with some examples & solutions.

Here's what I want it to look like first:
 - Alabama 
 - Alaska
 - Arkansas
 - etc..

Then if someone clicks on 'Alaska' the list would update to:
 - Alabama
 - Alaska
 -   Anchorage
 -   Fairbanks
 -   Juneau
 - Arkansas

Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT**

Ok, so I've been expelling jQuery I've come up with the following code. I can't get the states to individually show their respective cities. As is, if you click on any of the states, it only shows the cities for the first one.

Here's the code:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#city').hide();
$('.toggle').toggle(function(){
    $('#city').fadeIn(100);
},
function(){
    $('#city').fadeOut(100);
});
});

</script>
<%= render "layouts/header"%>

<table class="state_list">
<% @states.in_groups_of(1, false).each do |state| %>
  <tr>
<% for state in state %>
<td>    
<div class="toggle"><h3><%= state.name %><br /></h3></div>
    <% @cities.each do |city| %>
        <% if city.state.id == state.id %>
                    <div id="city"><%= link_to city.name, cities_path(:city_id => city.id) %> (<%= city.posts.where(:published => true).count %>)<br />
            <% end %>
        <% end %>   
</div>
    </td>
        <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Again, I appreciate any feedback!

Comment: Show us what you've got so far - you won't get much help asking people to write your code for you. :)

Comment: I appreciate the feedback... I just don't even know where to start. I'm exploring using the jQuery toggle in combination with iterating over the data... I think I'm close to having a code specific question now. I was just looking for some pointers on where to look...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StackOverflow Answer

I GOT IT!

Here's what I did for reference... Also, if you see a better method, please let me know.

```
<table class="state_list">
<% @states.in_groups_of(1, false).each do |state| %>
<tr>
<% for state in state %>
<td>    
    <script>
    $(function(){
            $('#city-<%=state.id%>').hide();
        $('#toggle-<%=state.id%>').toggle(function(){
            $('#city-<%=state.id%>').fadeIn(100);
        },
        function(){
            $('#city-<%=state.id%>').fadeOut(100);
        });
    });

    </script>
<div id="toggle-<%=state.id%>"><h3><%= state.name %><br /></h3></div>
    <% @cities.each do |city| %>
        <% if city.state.id == state.id %>
                    <div id="city-<%=state.id%>"><%= link_to city.name, cities_path(:city_id => city.id) %> (<%= city.posts.where(:published => true).count %>)<br />
            <% end %>
        <% end %>   
</div>
</td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Everything is working just like I hoped!